# RDD collect() failure

Tags: apache-spark, collect

A question that I feel may benefit others.

If I run

```
val rdd1  = sc.parallelize( List( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e")) 
val rdd1a = rdd1.map(x => (x, 110, 110 - x.toByte ))

rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[55] at parallelize at <console>:44
rdd1a: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[56] at map at <console>:46
```

it works.

As soon as I add collect

```
val rdd1  = sc.parallelize( List( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e")) 
val rdd1a = rdd1.map(x => (x, 110, 110 - x.toByte )).collect()
```

it fails.

The logic sort of escapes me really. Who can clarify? It is an RDD so?

Comment: That's because "map" is a lazy transformation that is not called until an action is called ("collect"). Your first example does not fail because map is not called yet

Comment: understood that, but the root cause is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here

```
val rdd1a = rdd1.map(x => (x, 110, 110 - x.toByte ))
```

Since `x` is `string` and you are trying to change it to `Byte`

what you should do is

```
val rdd1a = rdd1.map(x => (x, 110, 110 - x.toCharArray()(0).toByte ))
```

This did not failed here

```
val rdd1a = rdd1.map(x => (x, 110, 110 - x.toByte ))
```

because this is a lazy evaluation, it is not executed, `collect` is an action. After action is performed the code gets executed as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: If you are trying to ASCII code it converts to Char and converts to Byte